# Magento PDOException

Tags: sql, magento

I get the following error. What do i have to do? Is it something with the Collections or something else?

```
2013-01-10T00:22:41+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '')' at line 3' in /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(687): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(520): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#9 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(521): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#10 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(729): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#11 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api/V2.php(115): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#12 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api_V2->items(Object(stdClass))
#13 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(292): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Wsi/Handler.php(78): Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->call('c4922f9265fbeae...', 'order.list', Array)
#15 [internal function]: Mage_Api_Model_Server_WSI_Handler->__call('salesOrderList', Array)
#16 [internal function]: Mage_Api_Model_Server_WSI_Handler->salesOrderList(Object(stdClass))
#17 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php(832): SoapServer->handle('<s:Envelope xml...')
#18 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Wsi/Adapter/Soap.php(92): Zend_Soap_Server->handle()
#19 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server.php(84): Mage_Api_Model_Server_WSI_Adapter_Soap->run()
#20 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/controllers/V2/SoapController.php(46): Mage_Api_Model_Server->run()
#21 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Api_V2_SoapController->indexAction()
#22 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#23 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#24 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#25 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(642): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#26 /home/****/domains/****je.com/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#27 {main}
```

What do i have to do?

This is the part (line 228) in PDO.php where it refer to:

```
    public function _execute(array $params = null)
    {
        try {
            if ($params !== null) {
                return $this->_stmt->execute($params);
            } else {
                return $this->_stmt->execute();
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            #require_once 'Zend/Db/Statement/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Db_Statement_Exception($e->getMessage(), (int) $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
    }
```

Thanks
Jeroen

Comment: Please provide additional information.  Looks like your SQL is incorrect though.

Comment: Look at the error message - what SQL resides under `Statement/Pdo.php:228`? What parameters does it use/bind to?

Comment: Try uploading the core of Magento again via FTP. This solves a LOT of problems! Be sure you disable your cache first!

Comment: Why are you suddenly getting this error?  Have you upgraded either Magento or your PHP version?  Have you see this -> http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/224211/